# Xpath expression to get below output from input xml

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

*Input XML:*

```
<root><timestamp>2015-12-2</timestamp><record><e1>123</e1><e2>12366t6</e2></record><record><e1>123</e1><e2>0000</e2></record></root>
```

*Output XML:*

```
<root><timestamp>2015-12-2</timestamp><record><e1>123</e1><e2>0000</e2></record></root>
```

Could anyone help to find an XPath expression that can be used to achieve the above output? I have tried `$body/root[/record[2]]`, but it's not working.

Comment: remove extra `[]` from `$body/root[/record[2]]` as `$body/root/record[2]`

Comment: Thanks for your update!! Actually i need root element + timestamp along with record[2], but above expression will only give me record[2].

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets `[]` contain a *predicate* (similar to a `WHERE` in a SQL query).

Your expression `$body/root[/record[2]]` can be taken as

- Start at `body`
- take any `root`, but only if there is a `record` on the position 2

What you assumably want is `$body/root/record[2]`, which is

- Start at `body`
- take any `root`
- take any `record`, but return the second `record`only

If you cannot specify a fix position you can do something like this:

```
$body/root/record[(e2/text())[1]='0000']
```

Which is

- Start at `body`
- take any `root`
- take any `record`, but return only those, where the `e2` has the given value

### UPDATE: Back to your issue

You want to get two differnt components from your XML. You will have to use two `XPath` expressions

You might use something like this

```
/root/timestamp | /root/record[2]
```

or this

```
<root>
{/root/timestamp[1]}
{/root/record[2]}
</root>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - this will return only record element, but i need root element along with record. Hope this is clear now - if not please let me know.

Comment: Hi - i tried your solution but it did not work. can you suggest something else. I am expecting this - <root><timestamp>2015-12-2</timestamp><record><e1>123</e1><e2>0000</e2></record></root> and don;t want to hard code anything like root tag as this is my request message and there will be others elements along with timestamp element

Comment: @Sourav you are asking for some magic... `XQuery` is built to *query* XML data. As a result you get something back. In your case you are looking for different nodes, demanding for at least two `XQuery` attempts.  If you want to keep the `<root>` this is one more information the engine cannot know from light air... I'd suggest to close this question as the initial question seems to be answered. Avoid chameleon questions... It's better to start off a new question, add a realistic (but reduced) XML and the expected output. And add the technologies, languages you might use (as *tags*)

Comment: @Sourav btw: What does *did not work* mean? I tested this [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery) and it was working fine...